# BeautifulSoup <span>foo</span> result

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

HTML Code:

```html
<div id="descProdotto"> <img alt="Mont Blanc Eyewear" class="logoDesc" src="http://151.9.39.27/nfs/Immagini/Loghi_Linee/BA.png"/> <p><span>Nome:</span> BA0055</p> <p><span>Occh.:</span> Metallo</p> <p><span>Forma:</span> Geometrico</p> <p><span>Tipo:</span> Cerchiato</p> <p><span>Asta Flex:</span> No</p> <p><span>Fitting:</span> Caucasian</p> <img class="separatore" height="11" src="../../Grafica/Icone/separator_S.png" width="197"/>
<div class="glassDes">
<p class="scroll"></p>
</div>
```

Python Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_description(sorgente):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sorgente, 'html.parser')
    list = soup.find_all("p")
    for a in list:
        print(a.find('Nome:')

code = driver.page_source

get_description(code)
```

I can not extract the value in a variable: `Nome`: `BA0055`

How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Find the `span` element *by text* and get the [next sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
soup.find("span", text="Nome:").next_sibling
```

Comment: Not Work... 
this is the error
soup.find("span", text="Nome:").next_sibling
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'

Comment: @windsky are you sure you have this element in the `code` HTML string?

Comment: Absolutely yes.
I can not find solution to that error.